# Send packet to usb endpoint

Tags: usb

I need to send specified packet (5 byte) to usb zero endpoint.
My device installed as com port.
I use sample
[How to Access a USB Device by Using WinUSB Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#filehandle)

First question:
I not find my device if enumerate Ports class devices.
My device for some reason is in a Raw data class.
How can this be?

Second question: Why is WinUsb_Initialize() return error 87(INVALID PARAMETER).

```
//GUID InterfaceClassGuid = {0x4D36E978, 0xE325, 0x11CE, 0xBF, 0xC1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2B, 0xE1, 0x03, 0x18}; //Ports class
GUID InterfaceClassGuid = {0xA5DCBF10, 0x6530, 0x11D2, 0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED}; //Raw data

BOOL GetDeviceHandle (GUID guidDeviceInterface, PHANDLE hDeviceHandle){
...
//my code
WCHAR DeviceIDToFind[] = L"vid_xxxx&pid_xxxx";
// lpDevicePath is "\\?\usb#vid_xxxx&pid_xxxx#833435204e3334355f302083a5ada5e0a0e2aee0208faee1e2a0a2aaa0#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}"
WCHAR* res = wcsstr(lpDevicePath, DeviceIDToFind);
if (res!=NULL)
    break; //find our device
...
*hDeviceHandle = CreateFile (
    lpDevicePath,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);
    err = GetLastError();// err is 0
...
}
...
WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
BOOL bResult = WinUsb_Initialize(hDeviceHandle, &h);
err = GetLastError(); // err is 87 INVALID PARAMETER
```

Comment: I found answer [here](http://www.microchip.com/forums/tm.aspx?high=&m=653017&mpage=1).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Vendor ID and Product ID of your device.

your code snippet has the information.

```
WCHAR DeviceIDToFind[] = L"vid_xxxx&pid_xxxx";
```

this code has vendor id (`vid_xxxx`) and product id (`pid_xxxx`), which `xxxx` is hex number.

if your device has vid 3259 and pid 1001, you write `DeviceIDToFind` like below.

```
WCHAR DeviceIDToFind[] = L"vid_3259&pid_1001";
```

you have to have much understanding on usb specification.
Cheers.

Comment: Welcome!  Just a tip: code formatting makes a huge difference in readability.  Backticks (often above the tab key) are like quotes for small code snippets.  For whole lines of code, select the lines and press the `{}` button.